# SUMIF and multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am searching multiple sheets for a string, once this string is found it copies it to the MergedData sheet.

In column 1 is a payment number, for instance `50`. Column 2 is a work order number `11111`. Columns "3,4,5,6,7,8" or other information. "9,10,12" are £ values.

When this data is copied over there could be multiple instances on a work order number in column 2. I need to have a SUMIF to find any duplicates in column 2 and sum up columns "9, 10 & 12".

I have managed to get the code for the SUMIF working but I can't seem to get it to work after the data has been copied over.

What I need to happen is, when you click the button it searches for the string, and have it copy to the MergedData sheet, and on the same button click to perform the SUMIF function, after all the data has been copied.

Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated!

This is the code I am using to copy the data from multiple sheets into one:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    Dim FirstAddress As String, WhatFor As String
Dim Cell As Range, Sheet As Worksheet
Dim sSheetsWithData As String, sSheetsWithoutData As String
Dim lSheetRowsCopied As Long, lAllRowsCopied As Long
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim sOutput As String

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .CutCopyMode = False
End With

WhatFor = Sheets("SUB CON PAYMENT FORM").Range("L9")

Worksheets("MergedData").Cells.ClearContents

If WhatFor = Empty Then Exit Sub

For Each Sheet In Sheets
    If Sheet.Name <> "SUB CON PAYMENT FORM" And Sheet.Name <> "MergedData" And Sheet.Name <> "Details" Then
        bFound = False
        With Sheet.Columns(1)
            Set Cell = .Find(WhatFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
                bFound = True
                lSheetRowsCopied = 0
                FirstAddress = Cell.Address
                Do
                    lSheetRowsCopied = lSheetRowsCopied + 1
                    Cell.EntireRow.Copy
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MergedData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
                    Set Cell = .FindNext(Cell)
                Loop Until Cell Is Nothing Or Cell.Address = FirstAddress
            Else
                bFound = False
            End If
            If bFound Then
                sSheetsWithData = sSheetsWithData & "    " & Sheet.Name & " (" & lSheetRowsCopied & ")" & vbLf
                lAllRowsCopied = lAllRowsCopied + lSheetRowsCopied
            Else
                sSheetsWithoutData = sSheetsWithoutData & "    " & Sheet.Name & vbLf
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next Sheet

If sSheetsWithData <> vbNullString Then
    sOutput = "Sheets with data copied (# of rows)" & vbLf & vbLf & sSheetsWithData & vbLf & _
        "Total rows copied = " & lAllRowsCopied & vbLf & vbLf
Else
    sOutput = "No sheeTs contained data to be copied" & vbLf & vbLf
End If

If sSheetsWithoutData <> vbNullString Then
    sOutput = sOutput & "Sheets with no rows copied:" & vbLf & vbLf & sSheetsWithoutData
Else
    sOutput = sOutput & "All sheets had data that was copied."
End If

If sOutput <> vbNullString Then MsgBox sOutput, , "Copy Report"

With Worksheets("MergedData")
    If .Cells(1, 1).Value = vbNullString Then .Rows(1).Delete
End With

Set Cell = Nothing
End Sub
```

and this the other bit of code I am using for the SUMIF:

```
Sub combineduplicates()                 '### starts our macroApplication.ScreenUpdating = False      '### Excel wont update its screen while executing this macro. This is a huge performace boost
Dim SUMcols()                         '### declare a second empty array for our sum columns


SUMcols() = Array(9, 10, 12)         '### the second array stores the columns which should be summed up


'### the next line sets our range for searching dublicates. Starting at cell A2 and ending at the last used cell in column A
Set searchrange = Range([b2], Columns(2).Find(what:="*", after:=[b1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious))
For Each cell In searchrange            '### now we start looping through each cell of our searchrange

Set search = searchrange.Find(cell, after:=cell, lookat:=xlWhole)   '### searches for a dublicate. If no dub exists, it finds only itself
Do While search.Address <> cell.Address     '### until we find our starting cell again, these rows are all dublicates

    For i = 0 To UBound(SUMcols)    '### loop through all columns for calculating the sum
        '### next line sums up the cell in our starting row and its counterpart in its dublicate row
        Cells(cell.Row, SUMcols(i)) = CDbl(Cells(cell.Row, SUMcols(i))) + CDbl(Cells(search.Row, SUMcols(i)))
    Next i                          '### go ahead to the next column


    search.EntireRow.Delete         '### we are finished with this row. Delete the whole row
    Set search = searchrange.Find(cell, after:=cell)    '### and search the next dublicate after our starting row
Loop

Next                                    '### from here we start over with the next cell of our searchrange
                                    '### Note: This is a NEW unique value since we already deleted all old dublicates
Application.ScreenUpdating = True       '### re-enable our screen updating

End Sub                                 '### ends our macro
```

Comment: I haven't used .Find, but what happens when you change `Set search = searchrange.Find(cell, after:=cell, lookat:=xlWhole)` to `Set search = searchrange.Find(cell.value, after:=cell.address, lookat:=xlWhole)`?

Comment: You will also get more answers if you explain what is not working with the SUMIF function. Is there an error? Are the results not what you expect? Explain more.

Comment: @puzzlepiece87, basically i want the sumif to be run on the same button click, but after the data has been copied to the sheet. one the data is copied the the sumif code can run.

Comment: Right, but what is happening now? :)

Comment: @puzzlepiece87, well there in two different documents as the moment. 1 of the documents works fine with the merging data, and the other does the SUMIF fine, but i cant get then to work together. I have uploaded the documents if it makes it easier for you to understand. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1Z1ZIW5rn8Jfk5ObFB6TmdhajNTd2ltSm1SbGRyWUJMZ196MU5kbWNpaVYzbENTX1BIVzQ&authuser=0

Comment: I can't download those at work, but still might be able to help you. Are you saying they are in two different Excel files or two different sheets? You do not use any Workbook variables or qualifications in your code, so if you are using two different files that is probably why it does not understand. You would have to either merge the files or specify in your code which workbook/worksheet you mean. For example, in the SUMIF section you have Range B2, but you do not tell the code which workbook or worksheet that appears on.

Comment: @puzzlepiece87, the reason i have two workbooks is because i cant get the code to work within the same book. I created the SUMMIFF book to create the code and test, but when i tried to copy it to the Test Copy book it wouldnt perfrom the action, i think its not selecting the sheet. I need the SUMIF to work on MergedData sheet but i cant get it to work all the code i have tried to get it to select that sheet, give me a error, but doesnt explain what the error is.

Comment: Right, that's what I was thinking the problem might be. You need to tell the code which workbook and worksheet you mean when you are working. For example, if I am referring to the top left cell in a workbook called Test on a sheet called BigData, I'd use Workbooks("Test").Sheets("BigData").Cells(1,1). You need to change your code to include this information every time you are referring to objects on a sheet.

Comment: I dont mean to sound stupid, could you show me where to put this in the 2 piece of code? because when ive tried it doesn't work. thanks

Comment: You don't sound stupid. :) I am busy today and you need to learn how to qualify references to be a competent vba coder, so I will ask you to Google (search "vba qualify reference") this time rather than redoing your code. But to give you some examples from your above code, you would be better off if all of your .cells, range objects, and .Columns were qualified.

Comment: Hi all i am really struggling with this, i cannot seem to get this to work. The sumif works but only on the active sheet where as i need it to perfom on "MergeData", can anyone help me with this???

Comment: What new things did you try after reading up on vba qualified references?